# Comparing files two by two

Tags: bash, shell, compare

I need to compare files in a folder and now I manually go through them and run:

```
diff -w file1 file2 > file_with_difference
```

How can I compare them two at a time? What would make my life a lot easier would be something like this (pseudocode):

```
for eachfile in folder:
    diff -w filei filei+1 > file_with_differencei #the position of the file, because the name can vary randomly
                                                  
    i+=1                                          #so it goes to 3vs4 next time through the loop, 
                                                  #and not 2vs3
```

So it compares 1st with 2nd, 3rd-4th, and so on.
The folder always has even number of files.

Comment: I don't understand how you select the pair of files to compare ? if my folder contains `config.ini`, `data.yaml`, `main.go`, `output.json`, should I compare `config.ini` with `data.yaml`, then `main.go` with `output.json` ?

Comment: Yes, the folder structure is already set up, the files are in pairs, new_file_id_date - old_file_id_date. The task is to find difference between the two versions of the files.

Comment: fwiw : if you intend to compare two versions of the same directory, you can also set up two directories, `old/` and `new/` with files having *the exact same names* in both of them, and just run `diff old new`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the globing lists the files in the order you want:

```bash
declare -a list=( folder/* )

for (( i = 0; i < ${#list[@]}; i += 2 )); do
  if [[ -f "${list[i]}" ]] && [[ -f "${list[i + 1]}" ]]; then
    diff "${list[i]}" "${list[i + 1]}" > "file_with_difference_$i"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

@Renaud has a great answer.

Assuming your filenames do not contain whitespace, an alternative:

```bash
printf '%s %s\n' * |
  while read -r f1 f2; do
    diff "$f1" "$f2" > "diffs_$((++i))"
  done
```

Comment: Why not `printf '%s %s\n' *` to save the `paste`?

Comment: because I like paste? No, that's a great suggestion.

Comment: And note that to deal with fancy file names we could also use `NUL`: `declare -i i=0; printf '%s\0' folder/* | while read -r -d '' f1 && read -r -d '' f2; do diff "$f1" "$f2" > "file_with_difference_$i"; (( i += 2 )); done`